# Creating a libvirt URI to hop to another host

Tags: ssh, qemu, libvirt, uri

I have a Qemu-Host running libvirtd which is properly configured (h0). I can only access this host via another machine (c0), which only acts as a gateway. Now I need to know if it is possible to get a libvirt URI to connect via ssh to c0 and from there via ssh to h0. I am using virt-manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have such setup,

```
Libvirt IRL: qemu+ssh://user@host/system
```

And the setup password-less access to your `host` over your `gateway`, such as in `~/.ssh/config` (might need more configuration for additional keys, but I recommend to have the keys store in your `ssh-agent`):

```
Host c0
    Hostname real-gateway-hostname
    User gateway-username

Host h0
    HostName hostname
    User jjelen
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p c0
```

First verify that you can connect using

```
ssh user@host
```

and then "Add Connection" to your `virt-manager`, choose QEMU/KVM, remote host, method SSH, hostname and user as specified above. Then hit connect and you should be able to see your virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question from an eternity ago, and I don't know how it got accepted, but the dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt provider did not support ssh jumps.

I recently added a PR specifically for this [here](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/pull/1059/files).

The feature is absolutely not present in prior implementations.